# Reference other entities in entity_ruler

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

I'm tring to build a custom list of "named entities" using the entity_ruler, following also the [APIs](https://spacy.io/api/entityruler)

However I'm facing a problem: can I build a named entity that reference another one also defined in the entity_ruler?

To make an example, let's say I want to build the entity `Agreement` as some fixed expressions, and the entity `AgreementDate` as an `Agreement` followed by another expression:
can the following snipped correctly set spacy? Because the output is not what I was expecting.

```py
patterns = [
    {'label': 'Agreement', 'pattern': [{'LOWER': 'license agreement'}]},
    {'label': 'Agreement', 'pattern': [{'LOWER': 'agreement'}]},
    {'label': 'Agreement', 'pattern': [{'LOWER': 'commencement'}]},
    {'label': 'Agreement', 'pattern': [{'LOWER': 'parties'}]},
    {'label': 'AgreementDate', 'pattern': [{'ENT_TYPE': 'Agreement'}, {'LOWER': 'date'}]},
]
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
entity_ruler = nlp.add_pipe('entity_ruler', config={
    'validate': True,
    'overwrite_ents': True
})
entity_ruler.initialize(lambda: [], nlp=nlp, patterns=patterns)
for ent in nlp('''Commencement Date
license agreement date''').ents:
    print(f'{ent.text:40} {ent.label_:40}')
```

```
Commencement                             Agreement                               
agreement                                Agreement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity ruler patterns only match against the annotation that is set before the entity ruler component starts running, but you can do this if you move the final pattern into a second entity ruler (use a custom component name).

Comment: so the idea is to "split" the named entities and to assign them to multiple, indipendend entity rulers? Can you point me to some example to follow? Is there some way to "automatically" make it? at the end of the setup I'm not really sure of "how many levels" of references I would end up with

Comment: Just like code in a program, you need to think about the order your rules are executed in. There's no way to automatically make it.